# I will retrieve the information that is in object To perform in FormItem antd how to

Tags: reactjs, antd

https://ant.design/components/form/
[image]

---

`}}
            >
       <FormItem
                name="name"
                label="ชื่อ"
                onChange={this.handleChange}
           
                rules={[{ required: true, message: "โปรดระบุชื่อ ", }]}
              > 
                <Input />

      </FormItem>`

I will retrieve the information that is in object To perform in FormItem antd how to
I use the method set this.state.cus_fname in initalValue ={{naem:this.state.cus_fname}}
It is impossible to use this method.

Comment: Can you please clarify your question? It's not clear as to what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`<Form.Item>` does not have an `initialValues` props.

If you can check from the Ant design form documentation,

it is set at `<Form>` level.

```
<Form
      {...layout}
      name="basic"
      initialValues={{ remember: true }}
      onFinish={onFinish}
      onFinishFailed={onFinishFailed}
    >
```

After that, you will need to set a name at Form.Item to set the initial value of it.

```
<Form.Item {...tailLayout} name="remember" valuePropName="checked">
        <Checkbox>Remember me</Checkbox>
      </Form.Item>
```

I'm just referencing to the documentation url that you have provided.
https://ant.design/components/form/